# There's a way to change the audio device description?

Tags: windows-10, audio

I recently updated the CPU from a Ryzen 5 1600 to a Ryzen 5 5600G and the automatic device description, not the name that I gave it, changed from *Realtek High Definition Audio* to ***2-** Realtek High Definition Audio*.

I think that the previous name is around there in some Windows register.
I just want that Windows forget all the names and restart fresh or let me edit that and take out the **2-** prefix.

[image: Sound device automatic description]